# How can I include Audio Visualizations in my Delphi application?

Tags: delphi

hi there
I'm looking for some component or something to do this. I want a simple Oscilloscope visualization like KMPlayer,FLStudio,Multimedia Builder,etc.
What can i do?

Thnx in advance

Comment: @alexanoid: Wow, 5 years later! You indeed brought back my memories!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can

- build your own component. In order to do this, you need to understand a thing or two about digital audio. The WAV PCM file format (*.wav) is trivial -- I really mean it. In order to read other file formats, you need somehow to convert it to raw PCM data. For this you will probably need some library. Anyhow, when you got the data, you can use the `waveOut` functions of the Windows API to send chunks of sample data to the speakers, while computing and drawing the visualisation on-screen. Depending on exactly what kind of visualisation you want, you may also need to know about signal processing, particularly Fourier analysis and the FFT. If you just want to draw the waveform in some visually appealing form or another, you do not need much at all. But if you want to present the floating average intensity distribution of frequencies, in some sense, it is slighly more convoluted. When drawing the result, you'll need to master simple concepts such as double-buffering. Draw the result on an off-screen `TBitmap` and "swap the buffers", that is, `BitBlt` the off-screen bitmap to the screen, when appropriate.
- use an existing component. In this case, Google is your friend. One seemingly perfect match is   http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html  .

Comment: Thank you for the information. I actually prefer writing my very own component. Please if anyone has even more information about this please let us know.

Comment: @Javid: This is a too broad question (unless you want someone actually  to *write* the component for you).

Comment: I appreciate it, mate. I found the way to make it and I even found some samples about exactly what I wanted, so I can work with FFT (the most important keyword) and write the component.